# magento var folder

Tags: magento

A while back I was deleting Magento's cache in the var folder. I may be wrong but I think I made a mistake and instead of deleting everything in var/cache deleted everything in var accidentally. Magento seems to be running fine though. Have I got problems that I cant see, can anyone tell me?

Magento 1.6.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should be fine, the files in there are supposed to be temporary. Just make sure that you recreate the .htaccess file that was in there as it blocks the public from being able to see your log files if you have logging enabled. The .htaccess file just contains these lines:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the permissions are properly set on var/ , Magento will recreate the needed subfolders. You may need to create the import and export folders, watch for any other folders that may have been created by third party module installs, they should be recreated if the module programmer did their homework.

I've had situations where I actually had to delete all the folders in var/ so the web server could recreate them with the proper ownership (running as nobody).

Answer (score -1):

In the future in case you're interested in emptying your cache:

Simply delete everything from the /var/cache directory and then reload your website in your browser.

To clear all sessions, you can also delete everything from the /var/session folder within your Magento installation directory.

Comment: Doesn't answer question posed.